# Is WCF Service Host (wcfSvcHost.exe) limited to local client (localhost)?

Tags: wcf

I need to set up two machines later today for a domo of a client/server app written with WCF.  (Both machines have Visual Studio 2008 installed)

I have been testing the applications using the WCF Service Host (wcfSvcHost.exe) on my PC.

Will wcfSvcHost.exe let a client connect from a remote machine over HTTP (ideally port 80)?

Or is it limited to local clients (localhost) only like the Visual Studio 2008 inbuilt web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not limited to the local machine. You will need to config the project to use port 80. You may also need to open the firewall.

You should not use the wcfsvchost in a production environment

---

On Vista to use port 80, you also will need to run

> netsh http add urlacl
>   url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

with admin rights

On XP it is more complex...

Answer (score 0):

It is not limited, but you better build your own configurable host.
also -make sure you have no firewall blocking the ports that you are using...